# CHIP8 in C - How to correctly handle the delay timer?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, emulation, chip-8

**TL;DR** I need to emulate a timer in C that allows concurrent writes and reads, whilst preserving constant decrements at 60 Hz (not exactly, but approximately accurate). It will be part of a Linux CHIP8 emulator. Using a thread-based approach with shared memory and semaphores raises some accuracy problems, as well as race conditions depending on how the main thread uses the timer.

*Which is the best way to devise and implement such a timer?*

---

I am writing a Linux CHIP8 interpreter in C, module by module, in order to dive into the world of emulation.

I want my implementation to be as accurate as possible with the specifications. In that matter, timers have proven to be the most difficult modules for me.

Take for instance the delay timer. In the specifications, it is a "special" register, initally set at 0. There are specific opcodes that set a value to, and get it from the register.

If a value different from zero is entered into the register, it will automatically start decrementing itself, at a frequency of 60 Hz, stopping once zero is reached.

My idea regarding its implementation consists of the following:

1. The use of an ancillary thread that does the decrementing automatically, at a frequency of nearly 60 Hz by using `nanosleep()`. I use `fork()` to create the thread for the time being.
2. The use of shared memory via `mmap()` in order to allocate the timer register and store its value on it. This approach allows both the ancillary and the main thread to read from and write to the register.
3. The use of a semaphore to synchronise the access for both threads. I use `sem_open()` to create it, and `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` to lock and unlock the shared resource, respectively.

The following code snippet illustrates the concept:

```
void *p = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
/* Error checking here */

sem_t *mutex = sem_open("timersem", O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 1);
/* Error checking and unlinking */

int *val = (int *) p;
*val = 120; // 2-second delay

pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    // Child process
    while (*val > 0) { // Possible race condition
        sem_wait(mutex); // Possible loss of frequency depending on main thread code
        --(*val); // Safe access
        sem_post(mutex);
        /* Here it goes the nanosleep() */
    }
} else if (pid > 0) {
    // Parent process
    if (*val == 10) { // Possible race condition
        sem_wait(mutex);
        *val = 50; // Safe access
        sem_post(mutex);
    }
}
```

A potential problem I see with such implementation relies on the third point. If a program happens to *update* the timer register once it has reached a value *different from zero*, then the ancillary thread **must not** wait for the main thread to unlock the resource, or else the 60 Hz delay will not be fulfilled. This implies both threads may freely update and/or read the register (constant writes in the case of the ancillary thread), which obviously introduces race conditions.

Once I have explained what I am doing and what I try to achieve, my question is this:

*Which is the best way to devise and emulate a timer that allows concurrent writes and reads, whilst preserving an acceptable fixed frequency?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use threads and synchronization primitives (semaphores, shared memory, etc) for this. In fact, I'd go as far as to say: don't use threads for *anything* unless you explicitly need multi-processor concurrency. Synchronization is difficult to get right, and even more difficult to debug when you get it wrong.

Instead, figure out a way to implement this in a single thread. I'd recommend one of two approaches:

1. Keep track of the time the last value was written to the timer register. When reading from the register, calculate how long ago it was written to, and subtract an appropriate value from the result.
2. Keep track of how many instructions are being executed overall, and subtract 1 from the timer register every N instructions, where N is a large number such that N instructions is about 1/60 second.

Comment: +1 I agree with this. Keep it single-threaded or involve OS-primitives like signals, that can be set to fire periodically. Usable for emulating hw-timers or systick interrupts.

Comment: @MortenJensen Not signals. Signals are even worse than threads -- they're called asynchronously (interrupting any active system calls!), and most operations are unsafe to perform in signal handlers.

Comment: That's pretty clever! I guess I will implement method 1. Thanks for the response!